# Any Graphical interface for installing packages like php , mysql for UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu

In Cpanel/whm there is option to install various linux packages like php , mysql postgre sql etc.

Is there any option available in Ubuntu where i can tick the packages and those gets installed rather than writing on command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synaptic Package Manager is what you're looking for.  Should be under System -> Administration.

Comment: That'll work if you have Xorg installed. If not, I believe you're stuck with the CLI. Mirror51, you ought to learn to get comfortable on the CLI anyway. From previous posts, I know that you're looking to get into Sysadmin work. If you're truly going after that, you had better get somewhat comfortable on the CLI.

Comment: I think you are right. I will try to do stuff by CLI and will post what error i got :). Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude runs in a menuing system on a character terminal, but I agree that you should become accustomed to the CLI. Ubuntu uses apt-get and its relatives.

Comment: Aptitude can be used from the command line as well and doesn't have to be run in the interactive mode. It is also easier to use in some respects such as doing special dependency resolution. `aptitude install` > `apt-get install`

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement about that. Can you elaborate on how aptitude does dependency resolution differently than apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a utility that can be invoked from the command like called tasksel.  This will help you configure your server's role.  It sounds like the "LAMP Server" configuration might be what you're aiming toward.

From the Ubuntu Wiki:

> Tasksel groups software packages by tasks and offers an easy way to install all the packages needed for that task. It provides the same functionality as using conventional meta-packages.

Run it with the following command:

```
sudo tasksel
```